# Guidance & Info about Quadcopter Project

Tags: quad-copter

I'm new in forum and since I made some research the past days I'd like to get some guidance about constructing & programming a Quadcopter from scratch since I'm completely new on a project like that.

Quadcopter Frame: Thinking about to construct an aluminum 70cm diameter frame which will weight around 500g. What kind of motors should I get in order the frame with the board,motors etc. will be able to lift?

Board: I'm thinking to use Arduino Uno or Raspberry Pi 2.0 ( With a little bit of research I made I conclude that Raspberry could make my life a little bit easier since you can add wifi on it. The quadcopter will be controlled via a pc/laptop through wifi). What can you suggest and why?

ESC: As far as I've seen in most of similar projects people using ESCs in order to control the motors throttle. Can you avoid that, with programming PIDs that make the same job in order not to use more hardware?

About PIDs and Code in General: Thinking about to simulate the whole project in Simulik, Matlab and somehow (if it's possible) to convert the Matlab Code into C++ and download it on the chip. What do you think about that?

About the whole project: I'm trying to minmize the hardware as much as it's possible (use only 4x motors, the board with the chip on it, cables and probably some sensors) in order to minimize the total weight of construction and ofc the price.

That's all for a start. I'm gladly waiting for your answers and ideas.

Cheers  :)

Comment: About the battery you mentioned I'm thinking to use Turnigy nano-tech 2200mah 3S 35~70C Lipo Pack

Comment: You're trying to open an already wide open doors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of parts to this question; there are definitely homebrew quadcopter forums which might be better informed on the mechanical construction details, especially relating to motors and propellors. The item you haven't mentioned is the battery, which is critical to weight and flight time.

The use of ESCs is because the microcontroller cannot drive the current requirement of the motors directly.  Doing your own PWM-based motor control is not too hard; it doesn't even need to be closed-loop speed control. The flight control loop should be built around accelerometers/gyros.

Pi: can run Matlab directly on board, but has hefty power consumption.

Arduino: plenty of people have done it with Arduino, google tells me.

Matlab-to-C++ will not relieve you of the need to write glue code to drive various things. I wouldn't attempt this unless it was something I was very familiar with. You don't need matlab to do simple PID & Kalman filters, etc.

I'd strongly advise getting one of the open programmable quadcopter kits first (e.g. crazyflie) just to get some familiarity with the field.

Comment: About the battery you mentioned I'm thinking to use Turnigy nano-tech 2200mah 3S 35~70C Lipo Pack